# 3rd party authentication flow on Microsoft Teams App

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, microsoft-appstudio

I'm trying to achieve some results similar to what Asana App on Microsoft Teams has, when you paste a link from Asana their app/bot process the link and return a preview (link unfurling) but before that the app ask to login or sign up.

I'd like to develop the same authentication flow, get my user to login on my application from a PopUp on Microsoft Teams and only present cards and everything else after that. (asana is not using login with azure active directory)

Is there a way to send a token from my application and store on the Microsoft Teams user and then validate this token on my bot/app that will process the message and interact with my users?

Example of the results I'd like to achieve.[image]

Comment: Are you trying to implement basic authentication? Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth)? Also Could you please check this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57665326/calling-web-api-with-basic-authentication-in-c-sharp/57665644#57665644) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61728722/basic-authentication-instead-of-aad-azure-active-directory-authentication)? try if that helps

Comment: Is not exactly basic Authentication, but I'd like to use the auth from my web app not microsoft 365.
I'd like to have the same experience as the asana users have.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this, struggling with the same flow

Comment: No unfortunately, and I didn't find any material to help me.

Comment: You can implement the authentication and open the authentication page in the task module when clicks on the button.